# spring amqp enable retry by configuration and prevent it according to a specified exception

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-retry

I have the following two cases

1. In case of **ExceptionA** :  retrying for finite number of times
   and finally when number of retrials exhausted, message is written in
   a dead letter queue
2. In case of **ExceptionB** : simply, message should be written to
   dead letter queue

I want to support the two cases on the same listener container factory and the same queue.

I already have the following configuration to support **case 1** successfully:

```
@Bean
public RetryOperationsInterceptor workMessagesRetryInterceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .maxAttempts(5)
                .backOffOptions(1000, 2, 10000)
                .recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
                .build();
    }




@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory myRabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
  SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
  factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
  factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(8);
  factory.setAdviceChain(workMessagesRetryInterceptor());


  return factory;
}`
```

Now I want to extend the previous configuration to support case 2 too.

---

Edit, thanks Gary for your fast response.

Here you are my new configuration, but I still **get retrials** on both the two exceptions : ListenerExecutionFailedException , AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException

```
@Bean
    public SimpleRetryPolicy rejectionRetryPolicy(){

        Map<Class<? extends Throwable> , Boolean> exceptionsMap = new HashMap<Class<? extends Throwable> , Boolean>();
        exceptionsMap.put(ListenerExecutionFailedException.class, true); //retriable
        exceptionsMap.put(AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException.class, false);//not retriable


        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(5 , exceptionsMap );




        return retryPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryOperationsInterceptor workMessagesRetryInterceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless().retryPolicy(rejectionRetryPolicy())

                //.backOffOptions(1000, 2, 10000)
                //.recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide a `SimpleRetryPolicy` with a map of exceptions and booleans (whether or not to retry). You can optionally traverse the exception cause tree to find the specific exception. See the [Javadocs for SimpleRetryPolicy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/policy/SimpleRetryPolicy.java#L73).

Comment: You need to set the `traverseCauses` boolean to `true` because that exception gets wrapped in a `ListenerExecutionFailedException`. This is explained [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#_exception_classification_for_retry).

Comment: yes, that's it...But the message is not routed to the dead letter queue in both the two cases even with uncommenting the line : `recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())`

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice your exceptions - you can't use those two because the `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` is wrapped in the `ListenerExecutionFailedException` and we'll find that one first. You will have to throw a different exception and coerce it to an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` in a custom error handler. See [documentation about `FatalExceptionStrategy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#exception-handling). However, changing the policy won't affect DLX/DLQ routing if a message is rejected it will be routed to the DLX/DLQ by rabbit.

Comment: i.e. You can't use `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` to signal you don't want retry. If you want to retry for all exceptions except one, you need to throw `MyException` and configure the `FatalExceptionStrategy` to return true for that exception so the error handler will throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`.